# Uncaught TypeError: #<Object> is not a function

Tags: javascript

The following function returns the index of an object:

```
selectedAppIndex: function () {
  console.log(this.activeApps)
  console.log(this.selectedApp)
  return this.activeApps.findIndex(this.selectedApp)
}
```

`console.log(this.activeApps)` logs the array:

[image]

`console.log(this.selectedApp)` logs the object:

[image]

As you can see the object in the array and the object in `this.selectedApp` is the same. So the function should output `0`.

However I get this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: #<Object> is not a function`

(I'm using Chrome 49. And `findIndex()` is [supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) from Chrome 45.)

Comment: `this.activeApps` This is not an array. May be array like object. Are you sure that this is an array?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your problem is due the fact that `findIndex` expect a `function` as a parameter not an `object`.

Inside of this `function` you define the condition to find the first the `index` of the first match.

For example if you are looking for the index of the number 12:

```
 function  search12(el){
      return el === 12;
 }

 [4, 6, 8, 12].findIndex(search12);
```

The above example will return the number 3, since 12 is located on the index 3.

Inside of the `function` that is passed to `findIndex` you have 3 parameters that can be used for test.

- `element`, is the current element being processed present in the original array.
- `index`, The index of the current element being processed, or the result if the test evaluates to `true`.
- `array` The original array `findIndex` was called upon.

[More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).

As you can see on the function above you have to return the case where you have a match, because the `function` passed as a parameter is being executed every time per each element until is evaluated to `true` if some element evaluates to `true` will return that index if non element inside of the `array` evaluates to true will return `-1`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get the index of a value in an array, use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
return this.activeApps.indexOf(this.selectedApp)
```